# How to count with a group by in sql

Tags: sql, distinct-values

I have this query shown like below:

```
select 
    no, sub_no, date, id, count(distinct sub_no) as count
from 
    (select no, sub_no, date, id 
     from pre_test where type = 'B' and date = '2020-10-02'
     group by no, sub_no, date, id 
     having min(test_activity) = max(test_activity) 
        and min(test_activity) = 'APPROVED'
        and min(test_type) = max(test_type) 
        and min(test_type) = 'COMPLETED') as x 
group by 
    no, sub_no, date, id
```

What I expect from this query is to see how many `sub_no` in every `no` which has `type = B`, and all the `sub_no` have been approved and completed.

What I actually got:

```
no   sub_no    date          id        count
--------------------------------------------
01    01-01    2020-10-02     a         1
01    01-02    2020-10-02     a         1
```

While I expected that the query would return:

```
no   date          id   count
-----------------------------
01  2020-10-02     a      2
```

and also would show all `no` that have 0 value.

How should I fix my query?

Thank you.

Comment: What dbms are you using?

Comment: You take a subquery with `GROUP BY no, sub_no, date, id`, and then you wrap that in an outer query with `GROUP BY no, sub_no, date, id`, i.e. the **exact same groups**. Why would you do that? What's the point? It doesn't change anything. --- Also, if you're grouping by `sub_no`, then why would you expect `count(distinct sub_no)` to return anything other than 1? Not making any sense there. Re-think what you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `sub_no` from the `group by clause`

```
select no, date, id, count(distinct sub_no) as count
from (select no, sub_no, date, id 
      from pre_test where type = 'B' and date = '2020-10-02'
      group by no, sub_no, date, id 
      having min(test_activity) = max(test_activity ) and min(test_activity ) = 'APPROVED'
      and min(test_type) = max(test_type) and min(test_type) = 'COMPLETED') as x group by no, date, id
```